# Find the next closest class - jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, dom-events, simple-html-dom

I have these simple DOMs

```
<img src="{{$baby->babyBgPath}}" class="avatar img-thumbnail" alt="avatar">
<br>
<small class="hidden uploadingText">Uploading ...</small>
```

I've tried selecting them

```
$('.avatar').closest('.uploadingText').removeClass('hidden');
$('.avatar').find('.uploadingText').removeClass('hidden');
$('.avatar').next('.uploadingText').removeClass('hidden');
```

None of them works; Can someone please help ?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/siblings

Comment: closest() looks up the DOM tree for ancestors, find() looks for  descendants inside the matching selectors and the next element is the `<br>`

Comment: If your html structure always has a br tag between tags, then you can use this - `$('.avatar').next().next('.uploadingText').removeClass('hidden');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a sibling, and not necessarily the first sibling, so use [jQuery's `.nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) to select it.

```js
$('.avatar').nextAll('.uploadingText').removeClass('hidden');
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img width="200px" style="margin-top: 10%;" src="{{$baby->babyBgPath}}?q={{microtime()}}" class="avatar img-thumbnail" alt="bgImg">
<br>
<small class="hidden uploadingText">Uploading ...</small>
```